# Taking images from raspicam at 100 fps

Tags: python, camera, raspicam

I have been using my raspberry pi and working with the camera module. The lowest time taken by regular raspistill to capture a single image is about 900ms. I use the picamera python interface with video-port set & use camera_sequence function for format = jpeg the time to capture a frame comes down to 80 ms & 30 ms for yuv. Now the project that i am working on requires the time taken to capture a single frame to be at 10ms at least. I know that its possible if we put our raw image data on RAM (possibly the bayers data). Any ideas on how it can be done?

```
import io
import time
import picamera
import cv2

with picamera.Picamera() as camera:
    camera.resolustion = (750 , 150)
    camera.framerate = 80
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.shutter_speed = 400
    outputs = [io.BytesIO]
    start = time.time()
    camera.capture_sequence(outputs , 'jpeg' , use_video_port=True)
    finish = time.time()
    print(finish-start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to make it really fast.

1 Use [Asynchronous programming with AsynchIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to create separate process to shoot another photo while you still save the first one. Would be like

```
##Move those to some other function, preferably main
time.sleep(2) 
camera.shutter_speed = 400
##

outputs = [io.BytesIO] 
start = time.time() 

#Create i such processes:
def somefunction(semaphore)
    semaphore.Acquire() #Precreated semaphore get's taken by our process or process waits to be released
    camera.capture_sequence(outputs ,'jpeg' , use_video_port=True)
    #finish = time.time() print(finish-start)#Unneeded
    # Enable another process here
    semaphore.Release()
    # Do whatever you like here, time is not of the essence here (but be memory wise! it is limited in raspi!)
```

Should be pretty quick

2 Recursion could be the other solution

```
def somefunction(anchor, sequence)
    if sequence <= anchor :
        camera.capture_sequence(outputs ,'jpeg' , use_video_port=True)
        somefunction(anchor, sequence +1)
        #Save, or whatever, your photo here, be cautious about setting too large anchor, it might hang.
```

[link to recursion](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php)

[EDIT1]
Function should be placed like this:

```
with picamera.Picamera() as camera:
camera.resolustion = (750 , 150) 
camera.framerate = 80 
time.sleep(2) 
camera.shutter_speed = 400 
outputs = [io.BytesIO]
def function_taking_photo_as_short_as_possible_!_!_!(somearguments* somearguments_count**)
    #body
    pass

if __name__ = "__main__"
    #some simple console app waiting for
    #key to be pressed or whatever
    if keypressed:
        function_taking_photo_as_short_as_possible_!_!_!(none, none)
```

Comment: The less stuff you do in those functions that handle shooting photos the faster it gets. I doubt that it would be possible to make that 'picamera' package work faster then it already does.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong , you are saying that I must use another function to save image data which runs parallel with my image capture function hence saving me some time ..agreed that should help me when taking multiple images ..but right now I am testing for a single image acquisition time ..which is still at 80 ms for a jpeg while my target is 10 ms or closer to that ..once I am able to do it for a single image I will make it work for multiple images...any ideas regarding that.

Comment: Actually you are slightly wrong.
I would say that taking photo is around 30-40 ms, because it would represent like 30-40% of elementary operations in that call from where you set 'start' variable to where you set 'finish'. Because calling time.time() has some operations done (like for example, you call a package 'time') and you set a variable, which is an operation as well.

It is like trying to drive a car 5cm forward, when your engine is off i takes like a minute, but with engine on it takes like 10 seconds! So does this work, !single! frame will always be slow.

Comment: Pretty rough calculations with those percents xD

Comment: yes that's a valid point  , so lets say I re move the time part I can cut around 30 ms because it has its own operations ...and also I figured out that my overclocking needs to be set at 900 MHz which is currently at 600 MHz , so maybe even that effects the speed..we need to look at what other possible ways can we cut the time.

Comment: Most important is that those variables are set outside of the function taking photo (camera.framerate for example). Function should use global object that is preconfigured, and shoot when triggered (by user input for example)

Comment: camera.py is the file ..I have checked it , the variables are like global (what I figured with my limited python understanding) and the capture function accesses these global variables and then many other functions for encoding & creating camera component is being called.

Comment: Try to search if you can create camera component before shooting a photo. What I actually meant is that there should be something like [EDIT1]

Comment: yes I was thinking about it ..that we waste some time to create the camera component & encoding the raw bayer data to formats like jpeg ...I will try that and see if I find some success.